# SSRS - display matrix twice on each page

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have to write a report to print checks for our finance department. I am trying to replace an existing report written in Crystal.

The data set is automatically generated by our ERP system and I can't modify it. It contains a list of invoices with associated check number.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykrJm.png)

I need to page break the dataset by check number.
Each check page is broken into 3 perforated parts. The top part will have the summary check details using the header. The middle part has a list of the invoices associated with the check in the body with a total. Both of these are not a problem
My challenge is the bottom part needs to have a **second** copy of the list of invoices that gets detached by our finance department before mailing.

The next page is the next check with the same format. Like this:
[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLoz0.png)

Is it possible to get a second copy of the matrix on a page and have it page break properly like the first matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Subreport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/subreports-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) to accomplish this.

Create a report that has one instance of the transaction layout you need. The report must have a parameter for check number.

Then on another report have a tablix that calls the first report two separate times passing through your check number.

The tablix on the main report will control your page breaking. The sub report will display data.